# Passing a single column value returned by a MySQL query to PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to adapt the following code for the MySQL query below, but can't work out how to do so.  The query should just return one row, and I want to extract the data from the column 'Code' in this row and pass it as a variable to my PHP script.

```
/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Code from Clients where Name='Jane'")) {
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($code);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf($code);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've been working based on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php. However, you should follow it up on binding params, too:

```
/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Code from Clients where Name=?")) {

    /* bind query parameters to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", 'Jane');

    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($code);

    /* fetch values */
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf('Code: %s', $code);
    } else {
        print("Client code was not found");
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
```

You're preparing statements here, so you should bind your params separately.

Answer (score 0):

Go with:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Code from `Clients` where Name = 'Jane' LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($code);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

At the end of the script `$code` will contain the data from the column `Code`.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code to the following:

```
$value = $stmt->fetch();
```

Also if you know you want a single value from the database, you can speed it up a tiny bit, by doing a `'limit 1'` at the end of the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't waste too much code for such a trifle operation. Look, it's almost a whole screen long!
What if you need a dozen of variables throughout your code?
Encapsulate all the code into *helper function* and then call it **in one line:**

```
$code = $db->getOne("SELECT Code from Clients where Name='Jane'");
```